# Giving a formula for an integral and showing whether it can integrated

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have a question which states:

Given that $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a strictly increasing sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with $r_0 = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n = 1$ and that the function $f$ is defined by:

$$f: [0,1) \to [0, \infty):f(x) = \begin{cases} (x-r_n)^{-\alpha} & \text{if } r_n < x < r_{n+1} \text{ for } n\in \mathbb{N}\\
+\infty & \text{if } x=r_n \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{cases} $$

1. Give a formula for $\int_{[0,1)}f(x)dx$ in terms of $(r_n)$ and $\alpha$. Prove this formula. Consider $\alpha <1$ and $\alpha \geq 1$ separately.
2. Can you choose $\alpha >0$ and $(r_n)$ such that $\int_{[0,1)}f(x)dx < \infty $?

I don't really know where to start with this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n(x-r_k)^{-\alpha}\chi_{(r_k,r_{k+1})}(x)$$

and define $\tilde{f} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n$.

Note that $\tilde{f}=f \ \ a.e.$.

If $\alpha \neq 1$, we have(by the Monotone Convergence Theorem)

$$\int f d\mu = \int \tilde{f} d\mu=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(r_{k+1}-r_k)^{1-\alpha}}{1 - \alpha}$$

and if $\alpha=1$, we have

$$\int f d\mu = \int \tilde{f} d\mu=+\infty.$$

If $0 < \alpha < 1$, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (r_{k+1}-r_k)^{1-\alpha} > \sum_{k=0}^n (r_{k+1}-r_k)=r_{n+1} \to 1, \ \text{as} \ \  n \to \infty,$$

so

$$\int f d\mu = \int \tilde{f} d\mu=+\infty.$$

Finally, if $\alpha > 1$, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (r_{k+1}-r_k)^{1-\alpha} > Cn$$ for large $n$, where $C > 0$,

so

$$\int f d\mu = \int \tilde{f} d\mu=-\infty.$$

Comment: Does the sum given for $\alpha \neq 1$ always converge? If so, how can I show this?

Comment: @MathsBBB See the edit.